# MathJax local extension loading time

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I am using local version of both mhchem and arabic extensions for mathjax as I need to add some extra functions to arabic extensions and I am loading mathjax from https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js, my problem is when I load the extensions from local server it takes around 15sec to fully loaded and it gave an error `File failed to load: http://127.0.0.1:8887/HTMLEditor/MathJax/mhchem/mhchem.js` but both extensions working properly! and if I changed the `MathJax.Ajax.config.path` to get from https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/contrib it loads fast in less than a second without any errors.

I tried to stop loading of arabic extension to see if my edits cause an issue but I got the same result

Sample of my HTML (Note: I expect that it will not work for you because I load some of scripts and extensions from local server and that exactly my issue)

```
<html>

<head>
  <!-- <script src="arabic_mathjax.jsx"></script> -->
  <script>
    window.MathJax = {
        jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
        extensions: ["tex2jax.js", "[Contrib]/arabic/arabic.js", "[Contrib]/mhchem/mhchem.js"],
        TeX: {
          extensions: ["AMSmath.js", "AMSsymbols.js", "autoload-all.js"]
        },
        'HTML-CSS': {
              undefinedFamily: 'Amiri'
          },
        tex2jax: {
          inlineMath: [
            ['$', '$'],
            ["\\(", "\\)"]
          ],
          processEscapes: true
        },
        AuthorInit: function() {
          MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("Begin", function() {
            MathJax.Ajax.config.path["Contrib"] = "http://127.0.0.1:8887/HTMLEditor/MathJax";
              // your code to run once MathJax is ready, e.g., custom extensions etc.        
            MathJax.Hub.Queue( function(){
              // something to queue after the initial typesetting is done
            }
            );
          });
        }
      };
      
      (function(d, script) {
        script = d.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.async = true;
        script.onload = function() {
          // remote script has loaded
        };
        script.src = 'https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js';
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      }(document));
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        FixArabicCharacters($('.container'))
      });
      function FixArabicCharacters(node) {
        if ($(node).children().length > 0) {
          $(node).children().each(function () {
            FixArabicCharacters(this);
          });
        }
        else {
          var str = $(node).text()
          var regex = new RegExp("([\\u0621-\\u064A\\u0660-\\u0669])", "gm");
          if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf('<math style="displayed">') >= 0) {
            if (regex.test($(node).text())) {
              $(node).html("$$\\alwaysar{" + $(node)
                .text().replace('$', '').replace('<math style="displayed">', '').replace('</math>', '')
                .replace(regex, "\\fliph{\\text{$1}}") + "}$$");
            }
          }
          if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf('<math>') >= 0) {
            if (regex.test($(node).text())) {
              $(node).html("$\\alwaysar{" + $(node)
                .text().replace('$', '').replace('<math>', '').replace('</math>', '')
                .replace(regex, "\\fliph{\\text{$1}}") + "}$");
            }
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>input:</p>
  <input type="text" id="myid" oninput="DynamicMJ.update()">
  <p class="container" id="test"></p>

  <!-- <p><input type="button" value="Update" onclick="" /></p> -->

  <script>
    var DynamicMJ = {
      formula: document.getElementById("test"),

      update: function () {
        var a = document.getElementById("myid").value;
        this.formula.innerHTML = "\\[" + a + "\\]";
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, this.formula]);
      }
    };
    DynamicMJ.update();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

So please tell me, am I miss something?

Comment: Did you adjust the MathJax.Ajax.loadComplete call at the end of the extension file? It must match the contrib path you're setting up in your configuration, cf. http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/options/ThirdParty.html?highlight=loadComplete#custom-extension-path-configuration.

Comment: Thank you @PeterKrautzberger, this solved my issue